# Route53 + CloudFront + ELB + Apache2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

My record A is on Route 53 point to CloudFront distribution.
In the Origin Requests Policy, I choose whitelist all the viewer headers.

The Origin of CloudFront is an ELB, which have the 2 rules: port 80 route to 443 and 443 forward to an apache2 server.

I can use the DNS of EC2 and DNS of ELB to access my website but with the DNS of CloudFront is not, it give me the 502 error code.

I think we need to specify the domain.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-availables/domain.conf but I'm not sure which rules we should add more.
Here is the config I am using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com elbdomain.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
    <Directory /var/www/mydomain/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Did anyone face this issue before?

**EDIT:** Just add some space for easier view

**EDIT:** I raised a support ticket to AWS and received the answer. Actually we need to Whitelist the Host header both for Cache Policy and Origin Request Policy so that the ELB can use SSL from ACM to terminate it.

I think AWS documentation should have this note in.